# Pandoc Full Chicago Citation

Tags: pandoc, chicago-style

Colleagues,

I'm struggling to convert my book manuscript from LaTeX into a Word document for my publisher using Chicago citation style. In particular, they request the full/short Chicago citation footnote style. For sake of simplicity I've included a minimal working example:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testref.bib}
@article{Doe,
    author = {John Doe},
    journal = {Sample Journal},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1-20},
    title = {This is a sample title of the Pandoc reference},
    volume = {14},
    year = {2022}}
\end{filecontents}

% File is created and written to disk by the above package
\addbibresource{testref.bib}

\begin{document}

John Doe says ``This is a test of Pandoc output using Chicago style.''\footcite[2]{Doe} This is also a generic footnote for comparison.\footnote{A footnote appears here.}

\end{document}
```

With the desired footnote citation being:

1. John Doe, “This is a sample title of the Pandoc reference,” *Sample Journal* 14, no. 1 (2022): 2.

Using Mac Terminal, I inputted the following code,

`pandoc --citeproc Test.tex --bibliography=testref.bib --csl=chicago-fullnote-bibliography-short-title-subsequent.csl -o test.docx`

Unfortunately this resulted in the following error,

> File chicago-fullnote-bibliography-short-title-subsequent.csl not found in resource path

I copied the CSL code from [github.com/citation-style-language/styles](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles) and saved using TextEdit to my working directory (`cd ~/Desktop`). Unfortunately this still did not resolve the error.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note, I replaced the package preamble to ```\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}``` and ```\usepackage{endnotes}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I discovered the solution which required an additional Lua filter that is simply called with Pandoc. For example,

`pandoc --citeproc Test.tex --lua-filter=remove-parentheses-from-cite.lua --bibliography=testref.bib --csl=chicago-fullnote-bibliography-short-title-subsequent.csl -o test.docx`

The Lua filter is as follows (save in text editor with .lua extension):

```
  local lastInnermostElem = elemsList[#elemsList]
  if not lastInnermostElem.t == "Str" then
    getLastInnermostElem(lastInnermostElem)
  end
  return lastInnermostElem
end

local function getFirstInnermostElem(elemsList)
  local firstInnermostElem = elemsList[1]
  if not firstInnermostElem.t == "Str" then
    getFirstInnermostElem(firstInnermostElem)
  end
  return firstInnermostElem
end

local function removeTrailingSpace(formattedCitation)
  if formattedCitation[1].t == "Space" then
    formattedCitation:remove(1)
  end
end

local function removeParentheses(formattedCitation)
  local lastInnermostElem = getLastInnermostElem(formattedCitation)
  lastInnermostElem.text = string.gsub(lastInnermostElem.text, "%)$", "")
  local firstInnermostElem = getFirstInnermostElem(formattedCitation)
  firstInnermostElem.text = string.gsub(firstInnermostElem.text, "^%(", "")
end

local correct_citation = {
  Cite = function(cite)
    removeTrailingSpace(cite.content)
    removeParentheses(cite.content)
    return cite
  end
}

function Note(note)
  return pandoc.walk_inline(note, correct_citation)
end
```

Please note that I did *not* write this filter and can not take credit for it. Users in the Pandoc forum were kind enough to provide assistance and permitted me to share the filter with others who may have a similar issue converting their LaTeX files into Word documents with Chicago style citations.

I hope this proves helpful for others!

Comment: You forgot to copy-paste part of the function. Add the following before the first line to make your code compile:
`local function getLastInnermostElem(elemsList)`

Answer (score 0):

Update: I re-downloaded the citation style as a new csl-file from the [Zotero Style Repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles) and managed to succeed in generating a Word document! Everything looks great but I have a new issue with the style format that may prove problematic. In particular, citations within a footnote using the `\autocite` command appear in parentheses (although the LaTeX output appears fine):

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can remove the parentheses in footnotes? Would I have to manually edit the csl-file? Alternatively, perhaps there is a different csl-file from Zotero that would work?

Comment: This should be a new question rather than an answer.  Is there a different citation command, rather than `\autocite` that you can use?  (I'm also struggling with converting a book to Word using pandoc, but with a different starting point.)